# Save function requested

Tags: feature-request

Some times I come accross an answer that is super good, and I know I will need to look at this again.. I usually upvote such questions/answers.. but, some times it is  hard to find them again (unless I do something as oldfashion as bookmark it), so I would like to "save" it... for myself.. so that later I can look at my own "saved" answers, and this is a much smaller subset of all the answers out there (think reddit save funtion).

Comment: You can star the whole post as a favorite already.

Comment: that is true.. this is quite similar to what I want.. thank you